# How to see if a value for the key filter exists or not in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am a newbie in using twig. How to check if value "filter" exists or not from twig ?

```
    ParameterBag {#10 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "filter" => "news"
  ]
}
```

This is what I got from calling `{{ dump(app.request.query) }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
{% if foo %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Or if it's an array and you want to know if it's not empty, try

```
{% if foo is not empty %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this question while browsing through the net.

```
{% if foo is empty %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

This is my answer.